# mutable and immutable classes

Tags: java, oop, immutability, mutable

I want to create mutable and immutable node in java, both should be the same in everything except the mutable. how to implement the base class and the two derived class of mutable and immutable classes ?

Comment: What kind of "node" is this? What is the context? Should those classes be open for inheritance?

Answer (score 5):

The difference between mutable and immutable classes is that immutable classes have no setters or any other methods that modify internal state. The state can only be set in the constructor.

It would be a bad idea to call the parent class Immutable because this would no longer be true when you have subclasses. The name would be misleading:

```
ImmutableNode node = new MutableNode();
((MutableNode)node).change();
```

Comment: even without setters class can be modified with the use of reflection. Only final variables guarantees immutability

Comment: @myx: I agree that the fields *should* be  marked final in immutable classes (but for a different reason than you suggest). However that doesn't work here because then his subclassing idea isn't possible. The mutable class wouldn't be able to modify the final fields either. Though to be honest I don't like the idea of using inheritence for mutability in the first place. There are other ways to share code without using   inheritence: e.g. interfaces and composition.

Comment: @myx --- bzzztt.  You can change final variables via reflection ... except for static final fields that qualify as compile time constant expressions.  However, changing private and/or final variables via reflection is regarded as BAD BAD practice ... and is should only be done as a desperate last measure.

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is create a single base class with protected variables

```
public class Base{
     protected int foo;
}
```

The mutable one needs to be able to set the variable

```
public class MutableBase extends Base{
     public void setFoo(){}
}
```

The immmutable one needs to be able to set the variable only once

```
public class ImmutableBase extends Base{
     public ImmutableBase(int foo){
          this.foo = foo;
     }
}
```

Most immutable classes, have methods to act on the variable inside ***without*** mutating the instance.  String does this, you might want something like this

```
public ImmutableBase add(int bar){
     return new ImmutableBase(this.foo+bar);
}
```

The cool thing about this is that you give the users of your class ***less*** control/worry over the internals of each instance.  This makes it easier to work with, because in Java everything is passed by object reference, so if you're passing around a String or an ImmutableBase, you don't have to worry about it being changed.

Comment: Compilation error.  If you do it this way, `foo` can't be private.

Comment: what about declaring the field it self as final?

Comment: This doesn't make the class immutable, it makes the variable only allow one assignment.  Mutability as a concept arguably only applies to objects.  A immutable class may have mutable members or may not.  A primitive type has nothing to mutate - in the sense you can't reassign 4 to equal "foo", they are immutable, but this is a stretch

Answer (score 1):

Immutable class is a class which once created, it’s contents can not be changed. Immutable objects are the objects whose state can not be changed.

A common example of immutable class in Java is [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) class .

Answer (score 1):

for a class to be immutable it must be declared final, and it must not haver setter 
methods. the final declaration ensures that it cannot be extended and additional mutable properties added.

```
class Base {
    protected int var1;
    protected int var2;

    public getVar1() {return var1;}
    public getVar2() {return var2;}
    }

    class Mutable extends Base {
      public setVar1(int var1) {this.var1 = var1}
      public setVar2(int var2) {this.var2 = var2}
    }

    final class Immutable extends Base { //final to avoid being extended and then implement the setters

    }
```

Thats the little i can do? But why would you need such a scenario?

Comment: what about declaring the field it self as final?

Comment: because he wants a mutable version? if the field is final it cannot be set, yet the mutable version requires the field to be set.

Comment: While only a `final` class `Foo` can "guarantee" that an instance of `Foo` won't really be an instance of some evil mutable derived `Foo`, there are times when it may be helpful to have an inheritable, even abstract, class which is specified as immutable (meaning any derived class that's mutable would be considered "broken").  For example, in some contexts it may be useful to define an `ImmutableMatrix` abstract class, derivations of which would include `ImmutableArrayMatrix` (backed by an array the same size as the matrix), `ImmutableConstantMatrix` (backed by...

Comment: ...integers defining width and height, and one element defining the value for all elements), `ImmutableMergedMatrix` (which would hold references to a couple of two or more `ImmutableMatrix` instances and, for each, some integers defining the portion of that matrix which should be applied to the final matrix), etc.  If a particular application will be using matrices whose content fits some pattern which doesn't match any pre-existing implementations, it may be useful to be able to define a new class.  To be sure, derived classes which violate immutability would break things, but the fault...

Comment: ...would lie with the overridden versions of the class which failed to abide by the immutability spec.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the same strategy as the [UnmodifiableList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29). First, create an interface specifying the type.

```
interface List<T>{
    List<T> add(T t);
    T getAt(int i);
    ...
}
```

Then you implement your mutable class with all the business logic:

```
public class MutableList<T> implements List<T>{
    @Override
    List<T> add(T t){ ... }

    @Override
    T getAt(int i){ ... }

    ...
}
```

And finally, create your immutable class to be a view of the mutable one. You implement the same interface but delegate all read method calls to the viewed object, and forbid any write access with an Exception.

```
public class UnmodifiableList<T> implements List<T>{
    //This guy will do all hard work
    private List delegate;

    public UnmodifiableList(List<? extends T> delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    //Forbidden mutable operation: throw exception!
    @Override
    List<T> add(T t){ 
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("List is unmodifiable!");
    }

    //Allowed read operation: delegate
    @Override
    T getAt(int i){ 
        return delegate.getAt(i);
    }

    ...
}
```

This approach has the benefit that you implement the business logic only once, and can first build an Object using its own methods and validation checks before turning it into an imutable object.

Comment: It's important to note the distinction between objects that provide read-only views of potentially-mutable objects, and those which provide a read-only view of an object they create themselves and never expose in any context that might mutate it.  The term "unmodifiable" is a bit vague in that regard.  I prefer terms like "ReadableFoo" to refer to things that are known to be readable and cannot be *directly* modified, but could change via other means, and "ImmutableFoo" to refer to things that are guaranteed never to change, period.  "Unmodifiable" seems an odd middle ground.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The holder of the original list could change its contents, and that would be exposed to the view. On the other hand, a view is much more efficient, computational- and memory-wise. The right tool depends on what is the use, and unfortunately the asker didn't provide much information about it...